# Making a table responsive using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table to represent some data in html page.I'm trying to make this table as responsive by CSS.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Tell</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Maya</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2222555666</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I used to to do that by this way:

```
table thead {display:none}
table tr, table td{display:block}
table td:nth-of-type(1)::before {content: "Name";}
```

There is a problem, this way can be helpful when I know there are how many `<td></td>` and what the content of `<th></th>` is , but in this case I do not know the number of `<td></td>` and also the content of `<th></th>`?
What can I do?

Comment: Your way of solving this may work but is already wrong, working with tables you must not edit the display property of table components because that's all what a table is. Also tr as direct child of a table is invalid HTML

Comment: Thanks @Zohir Salak for your comment, now by your explanation how can I make this table as responsive?

Comment: The way i would do is to leave the table as it is, wrap it in a container with a max-width depending on the media query and make it scrollable